# Pixel 3a Live Caption

Tags: google-pixel-3-xl

I have bought a pixel and I update the phone to Android 10 but I can't put the live captions the option isn't there any help?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet available. It will probably be available with the new Pixel 4.

Source: https://www.theverge.com/2019/9/30/20891465/android-10-pixel-4-live-caption-accessibility-feature